# Json returns empty in android

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I created this class and I created my data in json. It seems that doesn't work and returns empty when I try to insert the data in a database sqLite. This is the class with the creation of the Json:

```
public class Corsa
 {
    public Corsa corsaData = null;
    public int id = 0;
    public String oraPartenza;
    public String oraArrivo;
    public String partenza;
    public String arrivo;
    public String codiceLinea;
    public String codiceCorsa;
    public String tipoCorsa;
    public String linkDettaglio;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return partenza + " / "+  oraPartenza + "\n" + arrivo + " / " +oraArrivo;

    }

    public Corsa() {

    }

    /** Json **/

    public static Corsa LoadJson(String jsonStr)
    {
        Corsa corsaJson = new Corsa();
        try 
        {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            corsaJson.oraPartenza = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "oraPartenza");
            corsaJson.oraArrivo = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "oraArrivo");
            corsaJson.partenza = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "partenza");
            corsaJson.arrivo = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "arrivo");
            corsaJson.linkDettaglio = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "linkDettaglio");
            corsaJson.codiceCorsa = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "codiceCorsa");
            corsaJson.codiceLinea = HtmlUtils.getJSonString(jObj, "codiceLinea");

        } 
        catch (Exception e)  { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return corsaJson;
    }

    public static JSONObject CreateJSon(Corsa corsaJson)
    {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try 
        {   
            jObj.put("oraPartenza", corsaJson.oraPartenza);
            jObj.put("oraArrivo", corsaJson.oraArrivo);
            jObj.put("partenza", corsaJson.partenza);
            jObj.put("arrivo", corsaJson.arrivo);
            jObj.put("linkDettaglio", corsaJson.linkDettaglio);
            jObj.put("codiceCorsa", corsaJson.codiceCorsa);
            jObj.put("codiceLinea", corsaJson.codiceLinea);

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

This is the saved json:

```
public static void SaveCorsa(Context context, Corsa c)
{
    DeleteCorsa(context, c);
    SqlHelper dbHelper = null;
    try {

        dbHelper = new SqlHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("CORSA_DATA", Corsa.CreateJSon(c.corsaData).toString());

        database.insert(TABLE_PREFERITI, null, initialValues);

        Log.d("Insert preferiti", initialValues.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (dbHelper!=null) dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

and the logCat returns `CORSA_DATA{}`..So it is empty.. But it's strange beacause is created in the activity..Any idea what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you do the Json part with PHP and use MySQL database. After all you can directly call / save in SQLite without even the use of Json. I think the problem there is you aren't specifying where you save / call the json file. Get a read about the assets folder of android.

Comment: mmh, you need to consider one thing i didn't write.. That datas are taken from web from a jsoup parsing.. Thinking, i suppose that until the parsing is done, the `Corsa` class is null (the objected are null).. because are not parsed yet.. so the json is null too.. Could be possible?

Comment: oh I see, then you should check the json before performing for example: if(jObj == null) //do this..

Comment: mmh..where exactly? in CreateJson?

Comment: Check all your json objects like it to prevent null pointer exception, also I think your problem is the url is not being retrieved well by jsoup / Corsa. Is that all your code?

Comment: the whole project is so big..there are a lot of classes.. This is the class with the objected i need to return when i shows the result after parsing. What i need to do right now is stored the result.. Everything goes ok after parsing and i can show what i need in a listview.. But i want save the whole list so i tried to get the json with everything i need and then stored the json.. but seems not work.. understand what i mean?

Comment: You don't need to store the json, You just recall them when you need them. Otherwise if you really want to store them then do Caching. So if you are retrieving them successfully then you might be having problem in recalling them, when you need them.

Comment: Can you help me if you send you my email please?

Comment: my email is mikeklintonlau@gmail.com I'll see what I can do.